# Calling Julia from R Issue

Tags: r, julia

I am using Julia 1.0.0 and R 3.5.1 and I am having an issue calling Julia from R/RStudio using both `JuliaCall` and `XRJulia`.

When I try:

```
library(JuliaCall)
julia <- julia_setup(JULIA_HOME = "C:\\Program Files\\Julia-1.0.0\\bin")
```

The Julia version is located but an error message pops up saying "libgcc_s_seh-1.dll is missing"

and when I try :

```
library(XRJulia)
JULIA_BIN <- "C:\\Program Files\\Julia-1.0.0\\bin"
findJulia(test=TRUE)
```

The test returns false.

However, when I call R from Julia using `RCall`, Julia can locate and use R (using Atom/Juno IDE). Both Julia and R are located in C:\Program Files path.

What is the correct way to call Julia from R/RStuio?

I looked [here](https://insightr.wordpress.com/2017/10/18/writing-julia-functions-in-r-with-examples/) for a solution but could not get it to work.

Update- I tried this solution so that R can recognize where the Julia files are located. When I restart my session and set the new env and then try to run the code below my R session just aborts

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"),"C:\\Program Files\\Julia-1.0.0\\bin",sep=";"))
library(JuliaCall)
julia <- julia_setup(JULIA_HOME = "C:\\Program Files\\Julia-1.0.0\\bin")
```

Comment: The error message from JuliaCall suggests that R is unable to find the dlls needed by julia, which should be in the folder of "C:\\Program Files\\Julia-1.0.0\\bin". Adding that path to the system PATH may help.

Comment: @Consistency I updated my post to include your suggestion. When I try to set system environment with the Julia path  and then run `julia_setup` my R session is immediately aborted

Comment: Did you try in the RStudio or in the command line R? It seems that Julia v1.0 currently has some issue with embedding in GUI application on Windows. But it should work in command line R.

Comment: Initially I used R Studio but I just tried the R console and when I try with JuliaCall it just closes out of my R session and XRJulia throws a warning. I am using a windows computer (windows 7).

Answer (score 1):

(This is more generic advice with dll issues with Julia.  If I get R installed, I'll try the exact situation.)

## Windows `SetDllDirectory` issues

I was getting a similar issue with PyInstaller calling another language.  It ended up being related to a call to `SetDllDirectory` in PyInstaller that modified the search path in an odd way.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectorya

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-subprocess#windows-dll-loading-order

To fix it, I just had to tell python to reset `SetDllDirectory` back to `NULL`.  I'm not entirely sure of the equivalent in R.

## SysInternals ListDlls

When debugging what dlls are getting loaded, I am a huge fan of this tool offered by SysInternals.  Download it, and run it with `ListDlls.exe julia` or `ListDlls.exe R` while `julia` or `R` is running.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/listdlls

## R `dyn.load` documentation

It also sounds like R tries to do a lot of things to find dlls if you load in a 3rd party dll, especially on Windows.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dyn.load

> The ‘standard mechanisms for loading DLLs’ include a search order for
>   where a DLL is found (if not given as an absolute path, which is
>   preferred), and of where its dependent DLLs will be found. This search
>   path depends on the version of Windows and its security settings, but
>   for versions since Windows XP SP1 it is
>
> - The directory from which the application was launched.
> - The various system directories, e.g.`c:/Windows/system32`,
>     `c:/Windows/system` and `c:/Windows`.
> - The current directory.
> - Along the search path for executables given by the environment
>     variable `PATH`.
>
> Packages often want to supply dependent DLLs in their `libs` directory,
>   and do this by setting the `PATH` variable (`library.dynam` does that
>   automatically in recent versions of R), but the DLL search order means
>   that DLLs in the launch directory and in system directories will be
>   preferred. On Windows XP SP1 and later there is a way to modify the
>   search order. If argument `DLLpath` is supplied to `dyn.load`, the latter
>   makes use of the Windows system call `SetDllDirectory` to insert the
>   value of `DLLpath` in second place, and removes the current directory,
>   for the duration of that `dyn.load` call. (Note that only one directory
>   can be inserted in this way.)
>
> Users have been confused by messages like
>
> ```
> error: unable to load shared object 
> '.../library/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':  
> LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
> ```
>
> The final line is a Windows (not
>   R) diagnostic: the ‘module’ that could not be found is not `rJava.dll`
>   but something else Windows is looking for (here most likely Java
>   DLLs): if you are lucky there will be a dialog box with more details.

## How Julia Loads Sys.dll

Julia 1.x current loads some dlls from the folder where the exe is in `bin/` and it also loads `sys.dll` from a nearby folder: `../lib/julia/sys.dll` .  You can override this by specifying where `sys.dll` is with the `-J` argument when calling julia.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer! It has been a while since I tried to integrate R and Julia, but with R 3.6.2 and Julia 1.3.1 using `JuliaCall` 0.17.1 I was able to integrate them. Here is the line of code I used `library(JuliaCall);
julia <- julia_setup(JULIA_HOME = "C:\\Program Files\\Julia-1.3.1\\bin")` . I think this answer is helpful still as others still might run into this issue.