# Error in Julia_setup() : Julia is not found

Tags: r, julia, juliacall

I am trying to use the [`JuliaCall`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/JuliaCall/readme/README.html) package to work with Julia in R. When I want to setup Julia using `julia_setup` I get an error. Here is the code:

```r
install.packages("JuliaCall")
library(JuliaCall)
install_julia()
#> [1] "Installed Julia to /Users/quinten/Library/Application Support/org.R-project.R/R/JuliaCall/julia/1.8.4/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia"

julia <- julia_setup()
#> Error in julia_setup(): Julia is not found.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this error?

---

**Edit: Trying julia_setup(rebuild = TRUE)**

When I try to use `julia_setup(rebuild = TRUE)` I get a warning message that Julia-1.8 is damaged and can't be opened. If I want to move it to the trash bin it says:

```
JuliaCall::julia_setup(rebuild = TRUE)
sh: /Users/quinten/Library/Application Support/org.R-project.R/R/JuliaCall/julia/1.8.4/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia: No such file or directory
Error in JuliaCall::julia_setup(rebuild = TRUE) : Julia is not found.
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521726/calling-julia-from-r-issue) help?

Comment: Hi @Sotos, Unfortunately not. Maybe there are some configuration problems with Mac.

Comment: 1. Create `JULIA_HOME` that points to your Julia installation location.  I do not have mac to test but perhaps this is something like `/Users/quinten/Library/Application Support/org.R-project.R/R/JuliaCall/julia/1.8.4/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia`.  2. Add `$JULIA_HOME/bin` to your system `PATH`. To test start console and see if `julia` command works.  After you are done with those two steps JuliaCall should work